# Finding sum in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I was trying to calculate the following sum in R and I get stuck because I can't find the right sum function in R. Any help will be appreciated.

`Sum(i, {i,1,10})`

The pseudo code for this can be as follows:

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    sum=i;
```

Comment: It would be great if you could supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from, something that show your "more complex sum," and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. That way others can also befit form your question, and the accompanying answer, in the future.  You can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: @EricFail I provided the picture of the sum.

Comment: @RichardScriven I am using the following code and I get an error message:

   rezult<-c(1:30)
n<-20
k<-5
for(a in 1:30){
  sum<-0
  for(i in 0:k-1){
    for(j in 0:n-1){
      sum<-sum+power(-1,j)*choose(n-1,j)*power((n-j-1)/n,a*k-1)
    }
  }
  result[a]<-sum
}

Comment: <?php
 
$sum=0;
 
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
 
{
    
 $sum=$sum+$i;   
 
} 
 
echo $sum;
 
?> for calculaing sum of 1-10  output is 55

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the docs (`?sum` in RStudio) but here are some things you can do with `sum`

```
mynumbers <- c(1:5, 13, 17, pi, factorial(5))
sum(mynumbers)
#[1] 168.1416
mynumbers2 <- c(1:5, 13, 17, NA, NA, pi, factorial(5))
sum(mynumbers2, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 168.1416
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
sum(1:10)
```

Comment: It helps, but I need it to calculate a more complex sum which has combinations and factorials. I was looking for the relevant function in r.

Comment: maybe you can post that more complex example here?

Comment: This is the sum I was trying to find but I don't get the right results. Any suggestion?

result<-c(1:30)
n<-20
k<-5
for(a in 1:30){
  sum<-0
  for(i in 0:k-1){
    for(j in 0:n-1){
      sum<-sum+(-1^j)*choose(n-1,j)*(((n-j-1)/n)^ (a*k-1))
    }
  }
  result[a]<-sum
}